# how to use mock object with smart pointer

Tags: c++, mocking, shared-ptr

I want to use mock object to test my class which uses shared_ptr pointer.

It likes ,

```
struct MyInterface {
    // public functions
};

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass (shared_ptr<MyInterface> handle) : m_handle(handle) {}
    ~MyClass() {}
   // ...
private :
   shared_ptr<MyInterface> m_handle;
}
```

When I test MyClass, I pass a mock object to it.

```
struct NullDeleter {template<typename T> void operator()(T*) {} };

TMockObject<MyInterface> * mock = new TMockObject<MyInterface>();
shared_ptr<MyInterface> handle((MyInterface*)(*mock), NullDeleter());

MyClass myClass(handle);
delete mock;
```

the question is I have to use a NullDeleter when i create the shared pointer, otherwise, mock will be delete as a MyInterface which cause error.

Is there any better design  for this ?

thanks~

Answer (score 0):

If I could understand what you want to do and I do not take the mistake,
I prefer to have method inside myClass class to check proper value of argument.
It means, you should after pass your argument to class constructor, provide another method to check the value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `virtual` destructor to `MyInterface`, and then when you delete an (abstract) `MyInterface`, all the sub class destructor is invoked as well.

```
struct MyInterface {
    virtual ~MyInterface() { }
    // public functions
};
```